# Modify values in a Map, removing digits from each String

Tags: java, hashmap

I've got `Hashmap`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

values in map:

```
{1=Thi1s, 2=is2, 3=3a, 4=T4est}
```

I need to remove digits from values like:

```
{1=This, 2=is, 3=a, 4=Test}
```

something like:

```
firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("\\d","");
```

but for `HashMap.`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You have to iterate over the map and replace as you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Map.replaceAll(BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) A full example is

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "Thi1s");
map.put(2, "is2");
map.put(3, "3a");
map.put(4, "T4est");
System.out.println(map);
map.replaceAll((i, s) -> s.replaceAll("\\d+", ""));
System.out.println(map);
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
{1=Thi1s, 2=is2, 3=3a, 4=T4est}
{1=This, 2=is, 3=a, 4=Test}
```

Alternatively, you *could* replace the digits when you add the values to the map in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and replace the value:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
    e.setValue(e.getValue().replaceAll("\\d", ""));
});
```